# Puppeteer: Is it possible to use click on a class with space in it?

Tags: javascript, bots, puppeteer

```html
await page.waitForSelector(".Buttonstyled__StyledButton-sc-140xkaw-1 btsair BasketButton__StyledButton-sc-1qvc90d-0 cvuMvs");
await page.click(".Buttonstyled__StyledButton-sc-140xkaw-1 btsair BasketButton__StyledButton-sc-1qvc90d-0 cvuMvs");
```

I'll always get this `TimeoutError: waiting for selector '.Buttonstyled__StyledButton-sc-140xkaw-1 btsair BasketButton__StyledButton-sc-1qvc90d-0 cvuMvs' failed: timeout 30000ms exceeded` error and I suspect that it may have to do with the fact, that there are spaces in the name of the class. [Here is how the button I want to click looks like when inspecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSN4H.png)

Comment: For future reference, please don't post images of text - it would be much more useful to have the HTML you took a screenshot of as text in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML class attribute is a **space-separated list** of class names, so there can never be a class with a space in its name, only an element which has multiple classes.

Meanwhile, in a CSS selector, a space is used to represent "any descendent", so ".foo bar" means "find an element matching .foo, then find any descendent of that which matches bar". The ".foo" means "has class foo", the "bar" means "the tag name is bar". So your selector is looking for completely the wrong thing, even though it looks reasonable at first glance.

To say "must have both class foo and class bar", the CSS selector would be ".foo.bar" (note that there is no space, and both classes are preceded by a dot). So in your case, the element would match ".Buttonstyled__StyledButton-sc-140xkaw-1.btsair.BasketButton__StyledButton-sc-1qvc90d-0.cvuMvs", or ".btsair.cvuMvs.BasketButton__StyledButton-sc-1qvc90d-0", or any other order or subset.

Possibly though you just want a simpler selector, such as ".btsair".

A more reliable thing to look for is probably the **id** of the element, which is a single string identifying a single element in the document. For that, you use a '#' prefix, so for your example would write "#php-add-to-cart-button".